# How can I execute a JavaScript function before the form submission handler is called?

Tags: 7, forms, javascript

I am trying to save an image using the following code.

```php
function mymodule_user_page_form() { 
  $form = array();

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Save',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'id' => 'myid_save',               
    ),
    '#submit' => array('mymodule_save'), 
  );
 
  return $form;
}

function mymodule_save($form, &$form_state) {  
  $save = db_update('student',array('target' => 'import'))
    ->fields(array('id_status' => '1'))
    ->condition('stud-id', '101-03043', '=')
    ->execute();

  if ($save) {
    drupal_set_message("Successfully saved.");
  }
}
```

The JavaScript file contains the following code.

```javascript
$('#myid_save').on('click', function(e) {           
  myid_save_signature();
  myid_save_photo();               
});
```

In my case, the JavaScript functions aren't called; the page refreshes before they are executed. I want to run those functions before `mymodule_save()` is called.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `#submit` from the form submission button.

```php
$form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => 'Save',
  '#attributes' => array(
    'id' => 'myid_save',               
  ),
);
```

Your submission function should be `mymodule_user_page_form_submit()` rather than `mymodule_save()`. If form builder is `myform_form()`, the the submission handler is `myform_form_submit()`. It will be automatically invoked.

Now change the JavaScript code to the following.

```javascript
$('#myid_save').on('click', function(e) {               
  myid_save_signature();  
  myid_save_photo();
  $('#myid_save').submit(); // Add this line                 
});
```

It will submit your form.

Comment: See the Op Comment on the question. OP is trying to save an image before submitting the form. If you submit the form immediately after calling those image save functions. There are 99% chance that image save will be interrupted and page will be re-loded due to form submission.

Comment: OP wants to run the js before submitting the form. The only way to do this is submit form using js or jquery.